# Magento 2 - 500 Internal Server error after setting permission to 775

Tags: magento2

I need to set the pub directory in my Magento 2 installation to 775 but when I set pub to 775 I'm getting an 500 Internal Server error.
I can set pub just to 755.

I see in the Magento DevDocs that the permissions for directories should be 775 and files 664.

Is this controlled by a .htaccess file or is this a server setting?

Comment: Please check your server's error log for details

Answer (score 0):

solved:

my Server Admin solved this problem. The Server was using suPHP. He replaced suPHP with CGI